# validation of csv using json schema in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, validation, schema, jsonschema

I want to perform the validation on the data. I have written the code using the pandas schema , instead of pandas schema how can I pass a json file which contains all the rules of validation in it and then apply it on the csv file.

That means to apply which rule on which column must be taken from the json file instead of the pandas schema and generate the error file.

```
def check_decimal(dec):
    try:
        Decimal(dec)
    except InvalidOperation:
        return False
    return True


def check_int(num):
    try:
        int(num)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True


def do_validation():
    # read the data
    data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

    # define validation elements
    decimal_validation = [CustomElementValidation(lambda d: check_decimal(d), 'is not decimal')]
    int_validation = [CustomElementValidation(lambda i: check_int(i), 'is not integer')]
    null_validation = [CustomElementValidation(lambda d: d is None, 'this field cannot be null')]

    # define validation schema

    schema = pandas_schema.Schema([
            Column('dec1', decimal_validation + null_validation),
            Column('dec2', decimal_validation),
            Column('dec3', decimal_validation),
            Column('dec4', decimal_validation),
            Column('dec5', decimal_validation),
            Column('dec6', decimal_validation),
            Column('dec7', decimal_validation),
            Column('company_id', int_validation + null_validation),
            Column('currency_id', int_validation + null_validation),
            Column('country_id', int_validation + null_validation)])


    # apply validation
    errors = schema.validate(data)
    errors_index_rows = [e.row for e in errors]
    data_clean = data.drop(index=errors_index_rows)

    # save data
    pd.DataFrame({'col':errors}).to_csv('errors55.csv')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I don't know anything really about `pandas_schema`, but if you have columns and their validators in a json like this:

```
{
    "dec1": ['decimal', 'null'],
    "dec2": ['decimal'],
    "dec3": ['decimal'],
    "dec4": ['decimal'],
    "dec5": ['decimal'],
    "dec6": ['decimal'],
    "dec7": ['decimal'],
    "company_id": ['int', 'null'],
    "currency_id": ['int', 'null'],
    "country_id": ['int', 'null']
}
```

Then you can use a dict of validators and a list comprehension to generate your `Column` objects for the `Schema`:

```
def check_decimal(dec):
    try:
        Decimal(dec)
    except InvalidOperation:
        return False
    return True


def check_int(num):
    try:
        int(num)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True


VALIDATORS = {
    'decimal': CustomElementValidation(lambda d: check_decimal(d), 'is not decimal'),
    'int': CustomElementValidation(lambda i: check_int(i), 'is not integer'),
    'null': CustomElementValidation(lambda d: d is None, 'this field cannot be null'),
}

def do_validation():
    # read the data
    data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
    with open('my_json_schema.json', 'r') as my_json:
        json_schema = json.load(my_json)

    column_list = [Column(k, [VALIDATORS[v] for v in vals]) for k, vals in json_schema.items()]
    schema = pandas_schema.Schema(column_list)

    # apply validation
    errors = schema.validate(data)
    errors_index_rows = [e.row for e in errors]
    data_clean = data.drop(index=errors_index_rows)

    # save data
    pd.DataFrame({'col':errors}).to_csv('errors55.csv')
```

**EDIT:**

For using validators with arguments defined in the JSON you are going to need to change up both the JSON format and the code a bit. The following *should* work, but I can't test it myself.

```
{
    "dec1": [['decimal'], ['null']],
    "dec2": [['decimal'], ['range', 0, 10]],
    "dec3": [['decimal']],
    "dec4": [['decimal']],
    "dec5": [['decimal']],
    "dec6": [['decimal']],
    "dec7": [['decimal']],
    "company_id": [['int'], ['null']],
    "currency_id": [['int'], ['null']],
    "country_id": [['int'], ['null']]
}


def get_validator(opts)
    VALIDATORS = {
        'decimal': (CustomElementValidation, [lambda d: check_decimal(d), 'is not decimal']),
        'int': (CustomElementValidation, [lambda i: check_int(i), 'is not integer']),
        'null': (CustomElementValidation, [lambda d: d is None, 'this field cannot be null']),
        'range': (InRangeValidation, []),
    }
    func, args = VALIDATORS[opts[0]]
    args.extend(opts[1:])
    return func(*args)


def do_validation():
    # read the data
    data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
    with open('my_json_schema.json', 'r') as my_json:
        json_schema = json.load(my_json)

    column_list = [Column(k, [get_validator(v) for v in vals]) for k, vals in json_schema.items()]
    schema = pandas_schema.Schema(column_list)

    # apply validation
    errors = schema.validate(data)
    errors_index_rows = [e.row for e in errors]
    data_clean = data.drop(index=errors_index_rows)

    # save data
    pd.DataFrame({'col':errors}).to_csv('errors55.csv')
```

Comment: how can I print the index at which error is occured in the saved csv @PyPingu

Comment: now it just prints the row at whixh error has occured @PyPingu

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Did it previously print the index and the row? Where/what is doing the printing, because there is no print statements in your code above. I'm guessing it is a `pandas_schema` thing?

Comment: how can i provide the range for any column in Json and apply the range on csv@PyPingu

Comment: Assuming you wanted to use `pandas-schema` `InRangeValidation` and you mean to specify the range in the json, then you would need to change the way you were handling validators entirely from this answer because right now they don't have an easy way to pass through parameters.

Comment: how can i proceed to do that@PyPingu

Comment: I've added another edit, but any future variations on this question should be addressed by creating a new question with the new problem. Not asked as comments here.